# Is the 6-th stroke of 您 Pie or Dian?

Tags: calligraphy, strokes

Consider the character 您

My dictionary says that the 6th stroke is 撇 whereas the 8th stroke is 点.

Is there a difference between how these strokes are written ?

I mean the short 撇 in 你 and the left falling 点 in 心.

They look identical to me.

Comment: The Eight Principles of [Yong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Principles_of_Yong)  explain how to write eight common strokes in regular script

Comment: You need to see it written with a calligraphy brush, which was how all Chinese characters were written originally. Normal computer graphical styles do not make such detail differences.

Comment: There's [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBeN36mv_c4) which confirms the claim.  (They look identical to me too.)

Comment: Take a look at this. It's only about 11 minutes long. It's worth your while. https://youtu.be/wM4BuhTFxho

Answer (score 2):

I got my answer.

Both the left-falling dian and the short pie look identical when not using a brush.

Both are drawn from top to bottom.

The difference is where the sharp end and the rounded end are.

Dian: Start with a sharp end and draw down finishing with a rounded end. Like a drop of water.

Pie: Start by drawing a rounded end at the top and then work down finishing with a sharp end going down. Like the drop of water upside-down.